# <ANDROID> Getting a string value from a sqlite database and assign it to a variable from another class

Tags: android, sqlite, variables

How to get a `String` value from my database then pass it to a `String` variable to another class so that I can use that value as my `number` field in this code: `SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(NUMBER /**string value that I've got from my DB*/, null, messageToSend, null,null);`

Answer (score 0):

Make a function on your Database class:

```
        public Cursor selectAll() {

           String query = "SELECT * FROM TB_number_table";
           System.out.println(query);
            cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            cur.moveToFirst();
            return cur;

          }
```

Call above class function on your class.

```
TB_class_name tb=new TB_class_name ();
Cursor c=tb.selectAll();
String number =c.getString(1);
```

`getString(1)` I am assuming your number in column one.

Cursor returns all values, then you can pass your value in your function.

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number , null, messageToSend, null,null);
```

Comment: u should add two more line tb.open();

Comment: and after cursor run u have to add c.open();

Comment: hm. like this?

`tb.open();
TB_class_name tb=new TB_class_name ();
Cursor c=tb.selectAll();
c.open();
String number =c.getString(1);`

Comment: u just doing mistake @ShiningCopper bcz u add tb.open before initiate class. I know it just a small mistake but code is like this  TB_class_name tb=new TB_class_name (); tb.open();  Cursor c=tb.selectAll(); c.open(); String number =c.getString(1);

Comment: there's no method `.open();` for c. -_- and one more thing, do I need to close my cursor after assign it to the string?

Comment: ur write im doing mistake TB_class_name tb=new TB_class_name (); tb.open(); Cursor c=tb.selectAll();  String number =c.getString(1); c.close(); tb.close();  sorry for mistake @ShiningCopper i apologies.

Comment: its okay, its only natural to make mistakes. Im only a newbie in android programming that's why Im having a hard time. BTW I've tried your answer but my application still force closing I really dont know what causing this. -_-

Comment: ru getting value from database?

Comment: i have another method though. that do the storing of value.

Comment: but u asked question for getting value now u said storing value.

Comment: yes. cos u asked if Im getting values from the DB. then I said that I've another method that do the _storing part_, THUS, the question I asked here is for getting that `stored` value from my db.